# change only some entries in /etc/fstab file in bash

Tags: bash, redhat

Below is a sample /etc/fstab with 9 entries.  How can I change column 4 (from-defaults to-noexec,nodev) for nfs shares only?  How can I use an exceptions file to do this? or is there any other way if i want to do this system wide?

```
/dev/appvg/me         /me     ext4    defaults        0 0
/dev/appvg/you         /you    ext4    defaults        0 0
/dev/appvg/we         /we     ext4    defaults        0 0
/dev/appvg/us         /us     ext4    defaults        0 0
nas-prd-unix.com:/vol/unix/he         /he     nfs    defaults        0 0
nas-prd-unix.com:/vol/unix/she         /she     nfs    defaults        0 0
nas-prd-unix.com:/vol/unix/it         /it     nfs    defaults        0 0
nas-prd-unix.com:/vol/unix/one         /one     nfs    defaults        0 0
nas-prd-unix.com:/vol/unix/two         /two     nfs    defaults        0 0
```

Comment: Please let us know [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/). Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Comment: I am sorry everyone, I got extremely busy with other project deadline that i  could not work on this.  but I have made changes to the question above and that is more likely the fstab that we have and we need to make changes to that.  i can use all the help i can get.  thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression with a look-behind assertion. These are supported by Perl, for example:

```
perl -pe 's/test[3469].*\Kdefaults/defaults,nodev/' /etc/fstab
```

To change the file in-place with a backup you can do:

```
perl -p -i.bak -e 's/test[3469].*\Kdefaults/defaults,nodev/' /etc/fstab
```

Answer (score 0):

In awk:

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /test[3469]/{sub(/defaults {6}/,"defaluts,nodev",$0)} 1' /etc/fstab
/dev/appvg/test1         /test1     nfs    defaults        0 0
/dev/appvg/test2         /test2     nfs    defaults        0 0
/dev/appvg/test3         /test3     nfs    defaluts,nodev  0 0
/dev/appvg/test4         /test4     nfs    defaluts,nodev  0 0
/dev/appvg/test5         /test5     nfs    defaults        0 0
/dev/appvg/test6         /test6     nfs    defaluts,nodev  0 0
/dev/appvg/test7         /test7     nfs    defaults        0 0
/dev/appvg/test8         /test8     nfs    defaults        0 0
/dev/appvg/test9         /test9     nfs    defaluts,nodev  0 0
```

If you insist on exclusion file:

```
$ cat exclusions.txt
/dev/appvg/test1
/dev/appvg/test2
/dev/appvg/test5
/dev/appvg/test7
/dev/appvg/test8
```

Script:

```
$ cat script.awk
NR==FNR { a[$1];next }                                  # remember exclusions
!($1 in a) { sub(/defaults {6}/,"defaluts,nodev",$0) }  # don't replace on them
1                                                       # print
```

Run it:

```
$ awk -f script.awk exclusions.txt /etc/fstab
# for output, see above.
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat similar to Eugene's answer...

```
# Your input data or file "data.txt"

bash$> cat data.txt
/dev/appvg/test1         /test1     nfs    defaults        0 0
/dev/appvg/test2         /test2     nfs    defaults        0 0
/dev/appvg/test3         /test3     nfs    defaults        0 0
/dev/appvg/test4         /test4     nfs    defaults        0 0
/dev/appvg/test5         /test5     nfs    defaults        0 0
/dev/appvg/test6         /test6     nfs    defaults        0 0
/dev/appvg/test7         /test7     nfs    defaults        0 0
/dev/appvg/test8         /test8     nfs    defaults        0 0
/dev/appvg/test9         /test9     nfs    defaults        0 0
bash$>

# Apply a perl command, which performs in place editing. 

** Caution: If you don't formulate the command properly, it may damage the file **

bash$> perl -pi -e 'if (m/test[3469]/) {$_ =~ s/defaults/defaults,nodev/g}' data.txt  ; cat data.txt
/dev/appvg/test1         /test1     nfs    defaults        0 0
/dev/appvg/test2         /test2     nfs    defaults        0 0
/dev/appvg/test3         /test3     nfs    defaults,nodev        0 0
/dev/appvg/test4         /test4     nfs    defaults,nodev        0 0
/dev/appvg/test5         /test5     nfs    defaults        0 0
/dev/appvg/test6         /test6     nfs    defaults,nodev        0 0
/dev/appvg/test7         /test7     nfs    defaults        0 0
/dev/appvg/test8         /test8     nfs    defaults        0 0
/dev/appvg/test9         /test9     nfs    defaults,nodev        0 0
bash$>
```

If you do this often enough, then use this script, and just feed parameters to it as shown and it will formulate a command and execute it for you.

```
# Script output

bash$> ./run.sh "test[3469]" "defaults" "defaults,nodev"
Formed Command is :     perl -pi -e 'if(m/test[3469]/) {s/defaults/defaults,nodev/g}' data.txt

/dev/appvg/test1         /test1     nfs    defaults        0 0
/dev/appvg/test2         /test2     nfs    defaults        0 0
/dev/appvg/test3         /test3     nfs    defaults,nodev        0 0
/dev/appvg/test4         /test4     nfs    defaults,nodev        0 0
/dev/appvg/test5         /test5     nfs    defaults        0 0
/dev/appvg/test6         /test6     nfs    defaults,nodev        0 0
/dev/appvg/test7         /test7     nfs    defaults        0 0
/dev/appvg/test8         /test8     nfs    defaults        0 0
/dev/appvg/test9         /test9     nfs    defaults,nodev        0 0
bash$>
```

Here is the script, which can be made general purpose if one needs to do this frequently, although this is not the only way. One can devise tonnes of other ways to arrive at the same result. This is just one approach.

```
bash$> cat run.sh
#!/bin/bash

# Taking Input parameters in a,b,c

a="$1"
b="$2"
c="$3"

# Old command for reference
#perl -pi -e 'if (m/test[3469]/) {$_ =~ s/defaults/defaults,nodev/g}' data.txt  ; cat data.txt

# Now formulate a command and use substitution
cmd="perl -pi -e 'if(m/$a/) {s/$b/$c/g}' data.txt"

echo "Formed Command is :       $cmd"

# Execute the formulated command
eval "$cmd"

# Check the output after execution.
echo ; cat data.txt
bash$>
```